# when trying to iterate a list of objects which contains a list of object and if i add a value to inner list all objects get same value

Tags: c#, object, reference, instance, listobject

my code is like this:

```
for(updatedDetails ud in meUD)
{
  Details s = 8;
  ud.Details.add(s);
}
```

meUD is List of object **updatedDetails**
which has a list of object **Details**

If I run that loop, instead of adding **s** to just the current **ud**, it gets added to all the object in the list.
I am not sure how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

It's adding s to all `ud` objects because the code in the block executes for all objects in `meUD`.

You can add a condition inside the loop to add the `s` object only to specific `ud` objects